# Does anyone use bootstrapping to report mass gain during experiment?

Tags: statistics

When performing an experiment to report gain of body mass in an experiment, do any of you know of a paper whose authors have used a bootstrap to improve their confidence intervals?

I have a n = 10 per group for a total of 6 groups, measuring whole body mass on a weekly basis in small animal models of a disease. Experimental design is essentially treatment by the use of a drug, over a period of ten weeks, and analysis of the final gain of body weight

(essentially think of a google search term as bootstrap, body mass, mouse)

Comment: Can you add more details? For example number of samples, metric measured, basic statistical estimates (mean/variance) and the experimental design. For your question, as it is now, searching `bootstrap+body mass` in google scholar would do.

Comment: @WYSIWYG I am not able to find a study that has explicitly used a bootstrap for body mass in the context I am seeking (see updated post).. am I missing the obvious here?

Comment: You should clarify why you want to use bootstrapping - what statistical tests you performed and what was the primary observation (which you say, has low significance). Is it 6 groups each for treated and control plus 10 individuals in a group? Anyways see [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17220561).

Comment: @WYSIWYG bootstrapping enables us to understand the true range of confidence intervals (and subsequently increase the accuracy) much more, than the usual way obtained by means and variances.

Comment: Also have a look at [this](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF03190460) paper. Basically what I wanted to ask was, whether you need bootstrapping. Is there some variation between groups?

Comment: @WYSIWYG the thing is, my mice are at their maximal body weight, and hence body weight gain is minimal, and since there is variation in each individual mouse is slightly masked by the std. error. It is significantly different by t tests, however an ANOVA followed by multiple comparison corrections masks the effect completely (1 test group ~ 5 control groups). So, I was recommended to go down the CI route (rather than a p value route) and I know from my stats lessons that bootstrap and CI's usually go hand in hand... does this make sense?